# Flexbox and UL/LI within article in layout - how to ensure it fits properly?

Tags: html, css

This is the skeleton of my code which is inline CSS currently as it's only testing, since inline CSS is discouraged mainly.

For some reason, text in article `li.infoheader1` does not move to the right even though I aligned it right in CSS.

In general, is a list within article good for this sort of thing (car showroom sales page list template) or is there a better alternative?

This started out as a HTML table, then became HTML5 `<header>`, `<article>` and `<footer>` in semantic HTML5 form, when are these advisable over `div`?

I am trying to make a simple template that's easy to use for MVC, here it's in static form so PHP isn't relevant for now, but if the individual who downloads it wants to be able to adapt it to work within an MVC framework, that's what I'm trying to do for compatibility.

Any help is appreciated.

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  column-span: 3;
  display: flex;
  margin: 5px;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
}

li img {
  width: 140px;
  margin: 5px;
}

article li.infoheader {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3px;
}

article li.infoheader1 {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <ul>
    <li class="infoheader">HONDA CIVIC 2.0 VTEC EX 4dr</li>
    <li class="infoheader1">£5995</li>
    <li><img src="https://i.imgur.com/TdqqLbK.jpg"></li>
    <li>2009, blue, 60,000 km</li>
    <li>&#9990; 555-0100-0000</li>
  </ul>
</article>
<article>
  <ul>
    <li class="infoheader">DETHLEFFS ESPRIT I7010 2.3 TD</li>
    <li class="infoheader1">£36995</li>
    <li><img src="https://i.imgur.com/cgatXO7.jpg"></li>
    <li>2010, 4 berth</li>
    <li>&#9990; 555-0100-0000</li>
  </ul>
</article>
```

Comment: The `text-align: right` is not having an effect because you've set `display: flex` on the `li`. If you're going to use flexbox, I'd suggest not using `li` as a container for inline content.

Comment: use `justify-content: flex-end;`

Comment: @Rory McCrossan: Is div a better alternative for within flex?

Comment: That's subjective based on the situation - however it is better than `li`, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps consider using Flexbox to target the content you want to right align. If this works for you, you can probably loose the text-align property.

```
article li.infoheader1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked well for what I needed.